# Pass form data from Spring Controller to an external endpoint

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

My issue:
Having a form in a simple HTML, with action="/myController".
I need to send the form data to my Controller and from there I need to make another POST to an external Controller.

```
<form method="post" action="/myController">
    <textarea name="data"></textarea>
</form>
```

And my Spring Controller looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/myController")
@ResponseBody
public String myController(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String[]> formData) {
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.postForEntity("urlPath", formData, String.class);
    String manipulatedResult = manipulateResult(response.getBody());
    return manipulatedResult;
}
```

I need to pass form data, to my controller, it should send form data further to the "urlPath" and recieve a response. I need to manipulate that response and return a result.
My question is, how to send the form data further, without manipulating the request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a GUI app I'm working on where I want to pass the request in its entity onto a web service for some calls which don't need GUI decoration (like, downloading a Word Doc link or some such.)  For these calls, I'd almost like to act as an intercepting proxy.  I think this is the problem the OP is getting at.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ModelAndView class.
Refer the following link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Response doesn't need to be a String it can be a well formed java object. In this case i do not see any issue returning ResponseEntity object without converting this into String.

@ResponseBody will convert returned java object to JSON/Xml based response to outside world.

Comment: The issue is not on my controller's response side, the issue appears when I am trying to post further the form data, I get an 500 error from the external endpoint, because the form parameters are altered or something.